# Boost, not caching

Tags: 7, caching

How does [HTTP Parallel Request & Threading Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/httprl) module help with Boost to increase performance ? How buggy is [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) module, cause it is giving me hard time not caching pages faster.

Comment: I have Refer to [LINK1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1357652) & [LINK2](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/httprl/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x#l487) & [LINK3](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34238/best-way-to-asynchronously-do-things-in-drupal?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Hi Abiyub, you might elaborate .. your questions seems to be a little unclear.

Comment: okay i will elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTPRL module doesn't increase Boost performance, per se. It is a requirement for the Boost Crawler submodule. The crawler module ensures all pages are actively cached; it goes through all site content and requests all its pages so that Boost stores them in its cache.

The HTTPRL module is used here to speed up the background crawler requests; it doesn't need to wait for a HTTP response to get the main Boost module to store things in its cache. The performance boost comes from having all your site content  cached so that no anonymous user doesn't take cache hit (i.e. they have wait for the site to build the cache since it's not ready).